# Convert object (time) type column in dataframe to datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.6

I am struggling to convert a object type to datetime.
It's a column from a dataframe which has time values in format hh:mm:ss.

dataframe: df_train
column: time
values in format: hh:mm:ss

Below are the options which I already tried without any luck

Opt1:

```
df_train['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['time'])
Error:
TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
```

Opt2:

```
df_train['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
Outcome:
The code is working but the type remain as object.
```

Opt3:

```
df_train['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['time'].str.strip(), format='%H:%M:%S')
Outcome:
value changed to NaT
```

Opt4:

```
df_train['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_train['time']).dt.time
Error:
TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime
```

Appreciate your suggestions to convert this column to type datetime.

Comment: you dont need `.dt.time` in Opt2

Comment: Thanks. I did tried and it changed the time format to timestamp.

Comment: Thanks. I did tried and it changed the time format to timestamp. for ex: 13:00:00 to 1900-01-01 13:00:00. But the type changed datetime as expected. Any suggestions how to remove the default date and keep time alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think close, what you need is [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) for timedeltas with convert python object times to strings:

```
df_train['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df_train['time'].astype(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
dat['column']  = pd.to_datetime(dat['column'])
```

OR
`pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['column'])` when reading data from file

Comment: Tried and getting the error TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime. Can't do this via read_csv since this column created from a timestamp in the run time.